# How would I use this void function to calculate the percentage?

Tags: c

I am working with DNA strands, so an input string will look something like: ATGC (with the possible bases A, T, G, and C)

I have to utilize this function: void updateGCCount(char s[], int * gc, int * at) to calculate the percentage of "GC" content in the input string.

The function, updateGCCount, sweeps through the contents of the input string, s, and updates the "GC" and "AT" counts appropriately.

What I don't understand is, if this function doesn't return anything, if it's void, then how do I use this to calculate the percentage of "GC" content?

Here's my code for the updateGCCount function:

```
void updateGCCount(char s[], int * gc, int * at){
   int i;

   for(i=0;i!='\0';i++){
      if(s[i]=='G' || s[i]=='C'){
         (*gc)++;                   /*Updated with the help of people who answered!*/
      }
      if(s[i]=='A' || s[i]=='T'){
         (*at)++;                   /*Updated with the help of people who answered!*/
      }
   }
}
```

And now here is my main function with the call to the above function (added this code on after receiving some help from the answers below):

```
int main(){
   char s[400];
   int gc, at;
   double percentage;

   scanf("%s", s);

   gc = 0;
   at = 0;

   updateGCCount(s, &gc, &at);
   percentage = (gc * 100.0)/(strlen(s) - 1);

   printf("Sequence  : %s\n", s);
   printf("GC-content: %.2f\n", percentage);

   return 0;
}
```

PROBLEMS I'M HAVING!
When I enter an input string of "ATCG", the percentage is 0 which isn't right and I can't figure out why it's giving me this problem! Help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `gc++` and `at++` increment pointers

Comment: So, if this increments the pointers, in the main function, would I have to use a for loop to go through the input string and then inside the for loop, would I call updateGCCount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment what `gc` and `at` point at:

```
(*gc)++;
(*at)++;
```

As it stands, you keep incrementing the pointers themselves, which may lead to problems (though, since you don't actually dereference the pointers, it may not lead to major problems).

You might call it with:

```
char *dna = ...;

int gc = 0;
int at = 0;

updateGCCount(dna, &gc, &at);
```

Now you just have to determine what the percentage means. Is it the number of pairs of GC out of the total number of adjacent pairs, or some other specification (like the total number of either G or C compared to the total length of the DNA strand)?

It is likely that you count not pairs but single characters, so the percentage you're after becomes:

```
double percentage_gc = (gc * 100.0) / strlen(dna);
```

You also need to fix the test for end of string:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Comment: Okay! Thanks! So, I tried this and when I ran it with the input string "ATGC", it gave me a percentage of 0. :( I was thinking it was because I set gc and at equal to 0 in the beginning but I need some help pinpointing my mistake(s). I'll update what I have so far in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`int * gc` is a pointer to a variable outside the function where the person calling the function wants the answer stored.  You want to increment the value at that pointer:

```
(* gc) ++ ;
```

instead of

```
gc ++ ;
```

Also you are not looking at the string passed in, so this loop is never going to exit.  Instead do:

```
int i; char c ;

for ( i= 0 ;  ((c= s[i])) ; i ++ ) {
  if ( c == 'G' || c == 'C' ) { (* gc) ++ ; }
```

etc.

Comment: loop above (in question) is never going to run because of `i!='\0'`

Comment: Please don't put spaces around the tightly binding unary operators like `*` and `++` (or, even more so, `.` and `->`, or `[]`).

Comment: @johny: are you sure? It is badly spaced but the condition is equivalent to `(c = s[i]) != '\0';`.

Comment: I use very tiny proportional spaced fonts for editing code, and the spaces help with readability on my systems.

Comment: If I really wanted to horrify the style police I could write the IF like `if ( ('G' == c ) || ('C' == c ))` which I prefer to do since that catches typos where you only use one `=`.

Comment: @woolstar consider editing code with a fixed width font; and take Jonathan Leffler's advice. He has enough of a track record that maybe, just maybe, he has a point…?

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed the problem with the pointers, but it's still not working.

You are not comparing "pairs", but individual characters; and your loop is all wrong. If you want to count "GC" (that is a G followed by a C), I think the following would work:

```
void updateGCCount(char s[], int * gc, int * at){
  int i, Length;
  Length = strlen(s);   /* new terminating condition for the loop */

  for( i = 0; i < Length - 1; i++ ) {
    if(s[i]=='G' && s[i+1] =='C') {
      (*gc)++;                   /* Updated with the help of people who answered! */
      i++;                       /* if you found G followed by C, skip one */
    }
    if(s[i]=='A' && s[i+1]=='T') {
      (*at)++;                   /* Updated with the help of people who answered! */
      i++;                       /* if you found A followed by T skip one */
    }
  }
}
```